# isotope overlapping after call items with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, fullpage.js

I'm working on website and using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) , with tow sections, I added a link to open a gallery into second section using ajax depending on the gallery link clicked, so the content changed .. I use isotope for images layout but the problem is images overlapping after ajax call, even I use  `$container.isotope( 'layout' );`

```
index.php

<div class="section">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="#" class="gallery-link" data-id="1"></a>
      <a href="#" class="gallery-link" data-id="2"></a>
      <a href="#" class="gallery-link" data-id="3"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="ajax_content"></div>
</div>
```

Now when I click on a link, it should call ajax request and get data from another page (`ajax.php`)

```
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
       <div class="item">
          <a class="fancylink" rel="sketch" href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>"/>
          </a>
       </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and the call method on click like this.

```
$('.slide').on('click','a',function(){

        var url = "ajax.php";
        var gid = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                 type : 'post',
                 url : url,
                 data : {
                     galleryid: gid
                 },
                 success : function( response ) {

                   $('.ajax_content').html('<div class="content" id="gallery-container">'
                   +'<div class="isotope">'+response+'</div></div>');

                   var $container = $('.isotope');

                   $container.isotope({
                         itemSelector: '.item',
                         masonry: {
                             columnWidth: 160,
                             isFitWidth: true
                         }
                   });

                   setTimeout(function(){
                        $container.isotope( 'layout' );
                   },100);

                       $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(3,0);
                   },

                       error: function( message ){
                            console.log(message);
                       }
                    });
                    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [imagesloaded.js](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js), which allows images to all load before isotope fires. If your using isotope v2 (imagesloaded is not included as it was in v1.56), download and add the script to your page then call isotope like this:

```
 var $container = $('.isotope');
 $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: 160,
        isFitWidth: true
    }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

what if you hide your images and show them progressively as they load (individually)

let me show you an example:

your HTML would be something like this

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="test.jpg"> </div>
</div>
```

Then hide your images with CSS

```
.item img {
   display: none;
}
```

now you initialize Isotope

```
$('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    percentPosition: true,
});
```

and finally with the help of the imagesLoaded plugin show your images as they get loaded in your page like this

```
$('.grid').imagesLoadedMB().progress( function(instance, imageObj) {
    $(imageObj.img).fadeIn(300);
    $('.grid').isotope('layout');
});
```

- you can find the imagesLoaded plugin here: http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/
- also I personally use this plugin which is ready to use (so I don't have to worry about things like this) https://codecanyon.net/item/media-boxes-portfolio-responsive-grid/5683020